# Having problems importing CSV into table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to import a CSV file into a table in order to do some queries. Eventually I'll automate this with SSIS to run daily. Unfortunately though, I'm getting an error.

I've run the task import data. Then chose my flat file, Under advanced I set all the types based on the types in the DB (this flat file will replace a table, so types should be the same). And I did check that the first row contains column names.

The type of my first column in Int in the DB, so in the data source, I tried DT_Numeric and DT_UI8. However, when I do the import, I get the following errors:

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task: Data conversion failed. The data
> conversion for column ""BLTO-NUM"" returned status value 2 and status
> text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of
> data.". (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code
> DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR. The "output column ""BLTO-NUM""
> (10)" failed because error code 0xC0209084 occurred, and the error row
> disposition on "output column ""BLTO-NUM"" (10)" specifies failure on
> error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified
> component. There may be error messages posted before this with more
> information about the failure. (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Any ideas as to what could be causing this? The field stays numeric.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Have you checked the output column width in the initial step of choosing a data source  to see if it's long enough to hold the import?

Comment: i will take a wild guess that data in your CSV is out of whack.   Can you try importing CSV file via BCP or bulk insert first?  that will remove SSIS from the equation.

Answer (score 2):

I would bring the data into a stage first and then change the data types with a simple cast statement. So for example you create a table with a bunch of `varchar(100)` fields. This will be your stage destination. Not the most efficient but it will only be populated for a minute. Then do an `INSERT INTO` statement with a `SELECT` into your destination target table. This is the ***Transform*** portion of ETL. `CAST` all your fields to the data type and data length described in your second target table

Here's an example although not relevant, hopefully should help describe my prose.

```
INSERT INTO [Staging].[EDITestCaseData]
           ([FileID]
           ,[ImportRecordID]
           ,[TestCaseID]
           ,[TestID]
           ,[TransmissionID]
           ,[GroupID]
           ,[SetID]
           ,[LoopID]
           ,[FileType]
           ,[FilePopulation]
           ,[DataDescription]
           ,[InterchangeReceiverID]
           ,[InterchangeDate]
           ,[InterchangeTime]
           ,[InterchangeControlNumber]
           ,[ApplicationSendersCode]
           ,[ApplicationReceiversCode]
           ,[FunctionalGroupDate]
           ,[FunctionalGroupTime]
           ,[FunctionalGroupControlNumber]
           ,[TransactionSetControlNumber]
           ,[SegmentDate]
           ,[SegmentTime]
           ,[MaintenanceTypeCode]
           ,[MaintenanceReasonCode]
           ,[EmploymentStatuscode]
           ,[RecipientID]
           ,[Site]
           ,[CaseIDNumber]
           ,[MedicaidBegin]
           ,[MedicaidEnd]
           ,[RecipientLastName]
           ,[RecipientFirstName]
           ,[TelephoneNumber]
           ,[CorrectedRecipientLastName]
           ,[CorrectedRecipientFirstName]
           ,[CaseAddress1]
           ,[CaseAddress2]
           ,[CaseCity]
           ,[CaseState]
           ,[CaseZip]
           ,[RecipientBirthdate]
           ,[RecipientGenderCode]
           ,[RaceEthnicityCode]
           ,[SpanishLanguage]
           ,[UseOfLanguageIndicator]
           ,[OldRecipientLastName]
           ,[OldRecipientFirstName]
           ,[OldRecipientBirthdate]
           ,[OldRecipientGenderCode]
           ,[CaseLastName]
           ,[CaseFirstName]
           ,[ResponsiblePersonTelephoneNumber]
           ,[InsuranceLineCode]
           ,[PlanCoverageDescr]
           ,[RetroactiveFlag]
           ,[BenefitBeginDate]
           ,[BenefitEndDate])
 SELECT
       CAST([FileID] as int)
      ,CAST([ImportRecordID] as int)
      ,CAST([TestCaseID] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([TestID] as varchar(10))
      ,null as [TransmissionID]
      ,null as [GroupID]
      ,null as [SetID]
      ,null as [LoopID]
      ,CAST([FileType] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([FilePopulation] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST(REPLACE([DataDescription], '"','') as varchar(5000)) as DataDescription
      ,CAST([InterchangeReceiverID] as varchar(15))
      ,CAST([InterchangeDate] as varchar(6))
      ,CAST([InterchangeTime] as varchar(4))
      ,CAST([InterchangeControlNumber] as varchar(9))
      ,CAST([ApplicationSendersCode] as varchar(15))
      ,CAST([ApplicationReceiversCode] as varchar(15))
      ,CAST([FunctionalGroupDate] as varchar(8))
      ,CAST([FunctionalGroupTime] as varchar(6))
      ,CAST([FunctionalGroupControlNumber] as varchar(9))
      ,CAST([TransactionSetControlNumber] as varchar(9))
      ,CAST([SegmentDate] as varchar(8))
      ,CAST([SegmentTime] as varchar(6))
      ,CAST([MaintenanceTypeCode] as varchar(3))
      ,CAST([MaintenanceReasonCode] as varchar(3))
      ,CAST([EmploymentStatusCode] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([RecipientID] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([OldSite] as varchar(50)) as Site
      ,CAST([CaseIDNumber] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([MedicaidBegin] as DATE)
      ,CAST([MedicaidEnd] as DATE)
      ,CAST([RecipientLastName] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([RecipientFirstName] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([TelephoneNumber] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CorrectedRecipientLastName] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CorrectedRecipientFirstName] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CaseAddress1] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CaseAddress2] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CaseCity] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CaseState] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CaseZip] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([RecipientBirthdate] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([RecipientGenderCode] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([RaceEthnicityCode] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([SpanishLanguage] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([UseOfLanguageIndicator] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([OldRecipientLastName] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([OldRecipientFirstName] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([OldRecipientBirthdate] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([OldRecipientGenderCode] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CaseLastName] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([CaseFirstName] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([ResponsiblePersonTelephoneNumber] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([InsuranceLineCode] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([PlanCoverageDescr] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([RetroactiveFlag] as varchar(50))
      ,CAST([BenefitBeginDate] as DATE)
      ,CAST([BenefitEndDate] as DATE)
  FROM [GenesisStaging].[Staging].[EDITestCaseData2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the issue was that commas were included in fields in the CSV, so the program couldn't properly make out the columns.
Thanks everyone! All great advice, especially the bcp and ETL!